# Given a sequence for the cubic root of a number $Y=\sqrt[3]{X}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, approximation

Given a sequence for the cubic root of a number $Y=\sqrt[3]{X}$, if $a>0$, show that Y always lies between a and $X/a^2$ (if $a<Y$, then $X/a^2 > Y$, etc)

I'm thinking use Newton's Method for approximation, use $a_{n+1}=a_n- \frac{f(a_n)}{f'(a_n)}$, I end up with $a_{n+1}=a_n-3a_n=-2a_n$. And I can't proceed, can someone tell me if I'm going the wrong direction?

Comment: Are you trying to show that $a<Y<\frac{X}{a^2}$ for all $a>0$? I'm not sure where the sequence comes into this question.

Comment: Done.  Too bad StackExchange doesn't ping you when an answer is substantially updated: I have to do it manually.  Please accept my answer so I can hit 1K rep and go to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newton's Method does not work in this case because there are certain hypotheses on the derivative that have to be satisfied in order for that method to work.

This looks like an application of the intermediate value theorem.  Have you tried that?  Or are you looking for another method?

Update: Let $f(x) = x^3 - X$.  If $a < Y$ then $f(a) = a^3 - Y^3 < 0$, and $f(X/a^2) = X^3 / a^6 - X > X^3 / Y^6 - X = X^3 / X^2 - X = 0$.

Similar argument if $a > Y$.

And don't forget that $f$ is continuous because it's a polynomial.

Comment: I think I know why the intermediate value theorem might work, but I don't how to start, can you show me?

Answer (score 0):

To use Newton's method to approximate $X^{1/3}$  for $X\ne 0$ let $g(y)=y^3-X.$ Let $y_0 \ne 0$ and let  $y_{n+1}=y_n-g(y_n)/g'(y_n)=(2 y_n^3+X)/3 y_n^2.$  Then  $y_n$ converges to $X^{1/3}.$  A modification of this  is  $Y_{n+1}=Y_n- Y_ng(Y_n)/(2 Y_n^3+X)$ which converges faster.